# How to create an custom event listener without a lambda function in Cocos2d-x 3.x?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

The new Event Dispatcher in Cocos2d-x 3.x has several test examples that show lambdas being used for the callbacks in the same class.  I have a base class that needs to register for an event, then have an overidden subclass method respond to that event.  How would I accomplish this?

In my base class:

```
EventListenerCustom* listener = EventListenerCustom::create("my_event", myVirtualEventMethod);
```

**Updated based on Kazuki's answer:**

```
class BaseScene : public cocos2d::Layer
{
    public:
    virtual void myVirtualEventMethod();
};
```

My method:

```
EventListenerCustom* listener = EventListenerCustom::create("my_event", CC_CALLBACK_1(BaseScene::myVirtualEventMethod, this));
```

See the error in comments below.

Comment: No viable conversion from '__bind<void (BaseScene::*)(), BaseScene , std::__1::placeholders::__ph<1>&>' to 'const std::function<void(Eventcustom)>'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EventListenerCustom::create() accepts std::function.

https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/v3/cocos/base/CCEventListenerCustom.h#L59

```
static EventListenerCustom* create(const std::string& eventName, const std::function<void(EventCustom*)>& callback)
```

So you can specify a member function with std::bind like this.

```
EventListenerCustom* listener = EventListenerCustom::create("my_event",
    std::bind(&YourSubclass::myVirtualEventMethod, this, std::placeholders::_1));
```

And there is a macro for it in cocos2d-x.

```
EventListenerCustom* listener = EventListenerCustom::create("my_event",
    CC_CALLBACK_1(YourSubclass::myVirtualEventMethod, this));
```

**EDITED**

```
No viable conversion from '__bind<void (BaseScene::*)(), BaseScene ,
    std::__1::placeholders::__ph<1>&>' to 'const std::function<void(Eventcustom)>'
```

Because the type of myVirtualEventMethod is not the same as **void(EventCustom*)**. Thus it should be

```
virtual void myVirtualEventMethod(EventCustom*);
```

Or

```
EventListenerCustom* listener = EventListenerCustom::create("my_event",
    CC_CALLBACK_0(YourSubclass::myVirtualEventMethod, this));
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  However, when I try the code you provide, I get this error: No viable conversion from '__bind<void (BaseScene::*)(), BaseScene *, std::__1::placeholders::__ph<1>&>' to 'const std::function<void(Eventcustom*)>'  I will edit above to show more code

Comment: Now I understand what's happening.  Thank you so much Kazuki for your help!